# User don't have access to the secret even after enabling the access though policy

Tags: policy, hashicorp-vault

I have created a policy so that a developer can access the secret but when I try to access the secret as a developer it shows that I don't have permission to access it.

I tried changing the value and adding new secret but nothing helped

```
 path "kv/*" {
     capabilities = ["list"]
     }
 path "kv/dev01"{
   capabilities = ["read", "list"]
   }
 path "kv/dev_01_cred" {
   capabilities = ["read", "list"]
 }
```

the developer should be able to read the secret in dev01 and dev_01_cred. 
Currently, the developer can only see the list of secrets in kv.

Comment: Are you using KV v1 or v2? If it's v2, you need a `data` in that path: `"kv/data/dev_01_cred"`

Comment: @sethvargo Thanks it worked perfectly. It was v2. Will path always change depending on the version.